# When a already existing pointer is pushed in a stack, does its copy gets created?

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, stl, stack

```
void deleteAllNodes ()
{
    stack <parentBranch *> mystack;

    // `trunk` is the existing head node
    mystack.push (trunk);

    cout << mystack.top ()->content;
}
```

In this case a "copy" of trunk gets pushed in the stack? So, does this means that at a time there are two trunks present in the memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope.  `trunk` points to an object, but isn't the object itself.  Like a sign that reads "Car -->" next to a car.  When you push `trunk` onto `mystack`, you don't get another car.  You just get another sign pointing to the same car.

Woe be it if you drive the car off (i.e. `delete trunk;`).  Then you'll have a whole bunch of signs that point to a car, but when someone comes along and tries to get in that car, they'll fall flat on their rear.  All the signs pointing to the car will be liars.

Comment: thanks to you too (nice example). So, does this mean that if we delete the pointer we pushed in the stack, the original trunk we get actually deleted?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  To clarify, if you `delete mystack.top();`, the original object you created will be destroyed.  Of course, you can always just get rid of the pointer (`mystack.pop();`).  This does nothing to the original object.

Answer (score 3):

No there is only one `trunk` but two pointers pointing to it.

This is the reason, Standard Library containers **do not take ownership** of deallocating memory of pointer members, because they cannot determine who actually *owns* the object being pointed to, the pointer which resides inside the container or the one which was used for push operation.

If you are using an pointer as container element, you are forced to do the manual memory management, it is up to the user to ensure the *pointed to* object remains valid.
This is the reason one should use **smart pointers** and not raw pointers with Standard Library containers, it saves you the manual memory management.

If the element being pushed in is not an pointer but an object then there will be two separate copies of the object, One which gets stored in the container and another which was used for push in to the container.

Comment: Thanks, was helpful. You mean the normal object if pushed will create copies of itself? Shallow copy?

Comment: @AnishaKaul: Yes a copy, by calling *copy constructor* just like one which gets created during function call pass by value. It would be a *shallow copy* or *deep copy* depending on the implementation of copy constructor.

Answer (score 3):

A *copy of the pointer* gets pushed, but not a copy of the object it points to.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So, does this mean that if we delete the pointer we pushed in the stack, the original trunk we get actually deleted?

Comment: @AnishaKaul, yes the actual `trunk` pointer's object is deleted from the heap. Because both the pointers were pointing to same location.

Comment: @AnishaKaul: You will be left with a dangling pointer and an UB.

Comment: Yes, calling `delete` on any of the two pointers "frees" the other one as well.